# How do I display error messages for nested resource validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I'm creating a basic blog application and I'm running into issues displaying error messages when a user tries to submit a blank comment. Instead of getting a nice looking error message, an active record error message with the correct validation erorrs. Such as 
    `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in CommentsController#create` 
    `Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Email can't be blank`

In my article/show view I have the following code:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @article %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

My error messages partial looks like this:

```
    <% if target.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from                 being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I know the answer is simple but I can't figure it out.

Create action in comments controller:

```
def create
@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
@comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "articles/show" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.  everything seemed to work fine, but I was not getting any errors
The solution i found is to build the comment in article#show instead of the view:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
```

and in your articles#show don't use @article.comments.build but @comment:

```
<%= form_for([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
   <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

make sure you build the comment in your comment#create as well (you really have no choice though :P)

also, I don't know if it matters (i'm pretty new to ruby), but I think you need to pass f.object instead of @comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're saying that you get the big grey-on-white error page, right?

Check the backtrace, but I suspect that this is coming from the `create` action in the controller, not the view.

If your controller uses `save!` with the `!` at the end, that means that it will raise an error if the record is invalid. `save`, on the other hand, returns true or false and lets you use simple branch logic to decide how to react.

If my hunch on `save!` isn't right, though, please post controller code so we can dig deeper :) Thanks!

Comment: I added the created action in the comments controller. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, now I have the app redirecting back to the correct controller and action, but no error messages. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to direct the comments created action back to the correct controller/action and target @comment in my error message partial.

Final view

```
    <%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @comment %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Final create action in comments controller

```
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "articles/show" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```